# subst variable names with "point"

Tags: tcl, subst

Let's say I have this code :

```
set a 1
set a.b a
set thing a.b
puts [subst $$thing]
```

The answer I would expect on the last line would be "a", but tcl answers 1.b
I tried to put \ everywhere before the . but it didn't changed anything.

Is there away to get a from thing variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl does not double evaluate two consecutive dollar signs.

The `$thing` characters in your command `subst $$thing` are first replaced by the value of `$thing`, which is `a.b`.

Subsequently, the `subst` command is evaluated like this:

```
subst $a.b
```

The above `subst` command replaces `$a` with `1`, which explains why you get `1.b` returned.

A reliable way to do multiple variable interpolation is with the `set` command without a second argument.  Chain together multiple `set` commands to interpolate multiple times.

```
puts [set thing]
  --> a.b
puts [set [set thing]]
  --> a
puts [set [set [set thing]]]
  --> 1
```

Comment: And if you're doing this a fair bit, consider using arrays instead. They're syntactically easier to use.